# How to modify this Entity framework code first code?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, ef-code-first

I am brand new to Entity Framework code first, so any help or direction would be much appreciated.

I currently have the following classes:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Address> _addresses;
}

public partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; };
    public string City { get; set; };
    public string Zip { get; set; };
}
```

and the following

```
public partial class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Customer");
        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);

        this.HasMany<Address>(c => c.Addresses)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("CustomerAddresses"));
    }
}
```

This works as I would expect, and creates a Customer, Address and CustomerAddresses table for the mapping. Now for my question.. what would I do if I needed to modify the code to produce the following...

I want to add a CompanyCode attribute to the "CustomerAddresses" table... and then instead of constructing a collection of addresses.. i want to be able to construct a hashtable, where the key is the CompanyCode, and the value is the collection of addresses.

So if I had the following:

```
Customer
ID     C1

Address
ID     A1
ID     A2

CustomerAddresses
CustomerID      C1
AddressID     A1
CompanyCode    ABC

CustomerID      C1
AddressID     A2
CompanyCode    ABC

CustomerID      C1
AddressID     A2
CompanyCode    XYZ
```

so then, Customer.Addresses["ABC"] would return a collection of addresses with ID, A1 and A2. Whereas Customer.Addresses["XYZ"] would return a collection of addresses with ID A2.

Any direction/help would be much appreciated... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it isn't possible to introduce such a navigation property with an indexer. Your indexer is actually a query and you must express this as a query. The only way I see is that you leave the navigation collection as is and introduce a second (not mapped) property that uses the navigation collection for the filter. The big drawback is that such a filter would happen in memory with LINQ-to-Objects and requires that you always load the full collection first from the database (by eager or lazy loading for example) before you filter the collection.

I would probably leave such a filter out of the entity itself and implement it in a repository or service class or generally the place/module where you load the entities from the database.

The first thing you need to do is exposing the `CustomerAddresses` table as an entity in your model because with your additional custom property `CompanyCode` you can't use a many-to-many relationship anymore, instead you need two one-to-many relationships. The new entity would look like this:

```
public partial class CustomerAddress
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    // public Customer Customer { get; set; } // optional

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
}
```

And the `Customer` needs to be changed to:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

You need to change the mapping to:

```
public CustomerMap()
{
    this.ToTable("Customer");
    this.HasKey(c => c.Id);

    this.HasMany(c => c.CustomerAddresses)
        .WithRequired() // or .WithRequired(ca => ca.Customer)
        .HasForeignKey(ca => ca.CustomerId);
}
```

And create a new mapping for the new entity:

```
public CustomerAddressMap()
{
    this.ToTable("CustomerAddresses");
    this.HasKey(ca => new { ca.CustomerId, ca.AddressId, ca.CompanyCode });
    // or what is the PK on that table?
    // Maybe you need an Id property if this key isn't unique

    this.HasRequired(ca => ca.Address)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(ca => ca.AddressId);
}
```

Now, in some service class you could load the filtered addresses:

```
public List<Address> GetAddresses(int customerId, string companyCode)
{
    return context.CustomerAddresses.Where(ca =>
        ca.CustomerId == customerId && ca.CompanyCode == companyCode)
        .ToList();
}
```

Or, if you want to load the customer together with the filtered addresses:

```
public Customer GetCustomer(int customerId, string companyCode)
{
    var customer = context.Customer.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == customerId);
    if (customer != null)
        context.Entry(customer).Collection(c => c.CustomerAddresses).Query()
            .Where(ca => ca.CompanyCode == companyCode)
            .Load();
    return customer;
}
```

The last example are *two* database queries.

In the `Customer` entity you could use a helper property that projects the addresses out of the `CustomerAddresses` collection:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses
    {
        get
        {
            if (CustomerAddresses != null)
                return CustomerAddresses.Select(ca => ca.Address);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this property does not query the database and the result relies on what is already loaded into `CustomerAddresses`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.. When you say that it will load the full collection.. do you mean, the full collection for a specific customer?

Comment: Ok thank you, i will try this out and let you know.. i really appreciate the amount of time and detail you put into your answer